# Negative (absolute) acoustic pressure in ultrasonic waves?

Tags: acoustics

I'm confused about the following problem:
in many papers they mention ultrasonic amplitudes, much larger than atmospheric pressure. For instance $P_A = 20 MPa$ at $f = 1 MHz$ is observed to cause lung damage. These pressures are probably relative to the static pressure, but I don't think that the static pressure in lungs is even close to $20 MPa$.

So superposition of the static pressure and the ultrasonic pressure with amplitude of $20 MPa$ would result in negative absolute pressures. I'm not entirely sure how I can understand this.

Are negative absolute pressures really obtained in the lungs during these experiments (I guess not)? If not, what is the meaning of the $20 MPa$ ultrasonic amplitude?

Comment: Can you provide the context (the source)? These kind of pressures are common in the ultrasound transducers and not in the air.

Comment: This is the paper of the lungs I was referring to (the 20 MPa is mentioned in the conclusion): http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030156299090046F. But a lot of other papers also mention these kind of pressures.

Comment: The pressures mentioned are most likely measured in water (or tissue with acoustic properties similar to these of water) and not in air.  So comparison with normal air pressure is not relevant.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, I would guess that the static pressure in water is of the same order of magnitude as the atmospheric pressure. In other words, I think that the static pressure can never be close to the 20 MPa. E.g., another paper about the effect of ultrasound on nerve excitation explicitly assumes static atmospheric pressure, while applying ultrasonic waves with amplitude of 500 kHz.

Comment: You know amplitudes don't have to fluctuate around 0, right?  Could it not have an average pressure of 10 MPa with 20 MPa peak pressure and 1 MHz frequency?

Comment: @JMac: in theory: yes. However, a static pressure of 10 MPa in the lungs sounds very unrealistic to me.

Comment: Wouldn't this be referring to external pressure?  I don't think your lungs are emitting 20 MPa waves at 1 MHz.

Answer (score 1):

In water, as in solids, you can have a state of tension as well as compression. If the amplitude of the acoustic wave is larger than the static pressure, you can have a state of "negative pressure" around the minimum of the acoustic pressure. This is better described as a state of tension in the medium.  Depending on the situation (purity, temperature) water cans sustain some amount of stretching. If some threshold is reached, cavitation occurs. This is one of the reason a too high pressure may be dangerous. The mechanical index of the ultrasound beam quantifies this danger, as it is expressed in terms of the minimum pressure of the ultrasound peak.

Comment: Such states would be metastable if the "tension" would be static. It is similar to overheating: because of the surface energy, bubbles need a sufficiently large radius to expand.